# Expected function body after function declarator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, unity-game-engine

Trying to compile a unity3d project in xcode but i'm getting the following compile errors on the function below. Anybody know what the cause is?

Using Xcode 4, SDK 4.3 and Unity 3.3
Base SDK is set to 4.3, SDK version in Unity is set to 4.2 and target iOS to 3.2

> AppController.mm:710: error: expected
>   initializer before '.' token
>
> AppController.mm: error: Parse Issue: Expected function body after function declarator

```
   void PresentContext_UnityCallback(struct UnityFrameStats const* unityFrameStats)
    {   
    #if ENABLE_INTERNAL_PROFILER
        _unityFrameStats = *unityFrameStats;

        if (_frameId % BLOCK_ON_GPU_EACH_NTH_FRAME == (BLOCK_ON_GPU_EACH_NTH_FRAME-1))
        {
            Prof_Int64 gpuTime0 = mach_absolute_time();

    #if ENABLE_BLOCK_ON_GPU_PROFILER
            UnityFinishRendering();
    #endif

            Prof_Int64 gpuTime1 = mach_absolute_time();
            _gpuDelta = gpuTime1 - gpuTime0;
        }
        else
            _gpuDelta = 0;
    #endif


    #if ENABLE_INTERNAL_PROFILER
        Prof_Int64 swapTime0 = mach_absolute_time();
    #endif

        PresentSurface(_surface);

    #if ENABLE_INTERNAL_PROFILER
        Prof_Int64 vblankTime = mach_absolute_time();

        if (_lastVBlankTime < 0) _lastVBlankTime = vblankTime;
        _frameDelta = vblankTime - _lastVBlankTime; _lastVBlankTime = vblankTime;

        Prof_Int64 swapTime1 = vblankTime;
        _swapDelta = swapTime1 - swapTime0;
    #endif
    }
```

The code prior to the above function is as follows:

```
void PresentSurface(MyEAGLSurface& surface)
{
    UNITY_DBG_LOG ("PresentSurface:\n");
    EAGLContext *oldContext = [EAGLContext currentContext];

    if (oldContext != _context)
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];

#if GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample
    if (surface.msaaSamples > 0 && _supportsMSAA)
    {
        UnityStartProfilerCounter(msaaResolveCounter);
        #if ENABLE_INTERNAL_PROFILER
        Prof_Int64 msaaTime0 = mach_absolute_time();
        #endif

        UNITY_DBG_LOG ("  ResolveMSAA: samples=%i msaaFBO=%i destFBO=%i\n", surface.msaaSamples, surface.msaaFramebuffer, surface.framebuffer);
        glBindFramebufferOES(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, surface.msaaFramebuffer); 
        glBindFramebufferOES(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, surface.framebuffer);

        glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE();
        CHECK_GL_ERROR();

        #if ENABLE_INTERNAL_PROFILER
        _msaaResolve += (mach_absolute_time() - msaaTime0);
        #endif
        UnityEndProfilerCounter(msaaResolveCounter);
    }
#endif

#if GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
    if (_supportsDiscard)
    {
        GLenum attachments[3];
        int discardCount = 0;
        if (surface.msaaSamples > 1 && _supportsMSAA)
            attachments[discardCount++] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES;

        if (surface.depthFormat)
            attachments[discardCount++] = GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES;

        attachments[discardCount++] = GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OES;

        GLenum target = (surface.msaaSamples > 1 && _supportsMSAA)? GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES;
        if (discardCount > 0)
            glDiscardFramebufferEXT(target, discardCount, attachments);
    }
#endif

    CHECK_GL_ERROR();

    // presentRenderbuffer presents currently bound RB, so make sure we have the correct one bound
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, surface.renderbuffer);   
    if(![_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES])
        EAGL_ERROR("swap renderbuffer");

#if GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample
    if (_supportsMSAA)
    {
        const int desiredMSAASamples = UnityGetDesiredMSAASampleCount(MSAA_DEFAULT_SAMPLE_COUNT);   
        if (surface.msaaSamples != desiredMSAASamples)
        {
            surface.msaaSamples = desiredMSAASamples;
            CreateSurfaceMultisampleBuffers(&surface);
            glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, surface.renderbuffer);
        }

        if (surface.msaaSamples > 1)
        {
            glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, surface.msaaFramebuffer);
            gDefaultFBO = surface.msaaFramebuffer;
            UNITY_DBG_LOG ("  glBindFramebufferOES (GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, %i); // PresentSurface\n", surface.msaaFramebuffer);
        }
    }
#endif

    if(oldContext != _context)
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:oldContext];
}
```

Comment: There is no '.' token (first error) in the snippet you've posted so this suggests it is a follow-on error and the problem is *before* the code you've quoted.

Comment: I amended the code but the #if statements ruin the layout.

Comment: @Zophiel. Please fix your code format. The reason the `#if` statements “ruin” your layout is that they are not fully indented. Please see http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode for further reference.

Comment: @Jonathan thank you for the link, i amended the post with proper formatting and supplied some more information.

Comment: The problem does not leap off the page, with the various `#ifdef`s and macros it is hard to see where the syntax is wrong. Run the file through the preprocessor and work backwards from the point the error is reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke turns out the problem lies inherently within Unity 3.3. How ever, this is easilly fixed by going into the player settings for iOS and readjusting the value for the tagrt SDK from "4.2" to "latest since 4.2"

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the & that was in front of the variable ... Now I can buld

Answer (score 0):

Add following two lines to my Prefix.pch

```
#define __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED   __IPHONE_4_2
#define __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED  __IPHONE_3_0
```